# Why does this directory rewrite only work for top-level content, not subdirectories?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have the following lines in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond         "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_legacy/%{REQUEST_URI}" -f
RewriteRule "^(.+)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_legacy/$1" [L]
```

While this works well enough for `/foo.html` to be found inside `/_legacy/foo.html`, it doesn't work for finding `/misc/bar.html` in `/_legacy/misc/bar.html`.

The weird thing is that when I try to access `/_legacy/misc/bar.html` I don't get a 404, I get a 403 permissions error. `/_legacy/misc/doesnt_exist.html` produces a 404.

My rewrites are clearly locating the correct file, but the permissions are somehow screwed up, and I haven't found a way to fix that part of the problem.

This is my motivation for trying to redirect access like this:

A while back I made the main page of my website an Angular app. I had older legacy content, however, that I didn't want to get rid of, but I also didn’t want that content all jumbled together with the Angular stuff.

So I created a directory called `_legacy`, and I’m using rewrites make the server look for anything it doesn’t find in the top-level directory inside the `_legacy` directory instead.

As I said, this is only working, however, for the root level content of the `_legacy` directory. The actual directory and file permissions are fine. I've tried using `FileMatch` and `DirectoryMatch` directives to expressly allow access to the subdirectories, but can't figure out anything that works.

Comment: What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? "... look for anything **it doesn’t find in the top-level directory** inside the `_legacy` directory instead" - Although that's not what the rule does that you've posted. The rule you've posted _prioritises_ anything in the `_legacy` subdirectory (even if it exists in the root). "when I try to access `/_legacy/misc/bar.html` I don't get a 404, I get a 403" - that is when you try to access the file directly? Or are you requesting `/misc/bar.html` and expecting the request to be rewritten?

Comment: I'm expecting a request for `/misc/bar.html` to be fulfilled by `/_legacy/misc/bar.html` if that file exists. If it doesn't exist, and `/misc/bar.html` also doesn't exist, I'd expect to get a 404 rather than a 403.

Comment: Since there is no `/misc` directory, is that the reason for a 403 instead of a 404 error?